# How to store file info in database after upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design

I want to store file information after the file is uploaded to our server using c#. Basically we have two storage locations, ie. local storage and cloud storage.

Structure of DB is

```
ID        int
CreateOn  smalldatetime
FileUrl  nvarchar(max)
StoreTypeID int
```

`FileUrl` stores url of the file, but not path and filename.

The problem is if I would like to delete this file from both DB and storage, if the storage is local I dont have a path to access the file, and if it is in the cloud there should not be any problem.

My question is should I also track columns

```
Path
Filename
```

In order to access local files?

Filename column could be avoided by extracting filename from fileurl.

Comment: Why you set the `FileUrl` to `nvarchar(max)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ID        int
CreateOn  smalldatetime
FileUrl  nvarchar(max)
FilePath nvarchar(300)
StoreTypeID int
```

Just add the path to your db.

By having the path variable, you will be able access the file on the file system, and you can get the fileName by `Path.GetFileName(dbObject.FilePath)` if you need to.

---

But a better approach would be like this.

```
ID        int
CreateOn  smalldatetime
FileUrl  nvarchar(max)
FileName nvarchar(300)
StoreTypeID int
```

Don't store your files with the name the user provided, either on local or cloud storage. But record the file name into the db along with your file.

When you are going to keep the file on the local storage, have a constant path variable that you know at your code level(better via configuration), then append it with a predefined or calculated path with the file id., hence you will know the exact location your file resides.

Comment: So you agree to mix file info for both cloud and local?

Comment: yeah, why not. Actually, you already did that by putting the `StoreTypeID` on your table.

Comment: Having calculated path would cause multiple db roundtrips, which I want to avoid. Also I have large number of containers/directories...  What about 
ID        int
CreateOn  smalldatetime
PhysicalPath nvarchar(max) //includes filename
FileUrl nvarchar(max)
OriginalFileName nvarchar(300)
StoreTypeID int